# Freeze the axes size in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I have images captured in many frames. All the frames have different sizes so I set the global maximum and minimum of each axes and used `axis` command like below:

```
h = figure;
axis([-8.4188e+03 -7.9061e+03 -102.6261 518.2502 -25.4673 0.2780])
%axis tight manual % this ensures that getframe() returns a consistent size
filename = 'testanim.gif';
```

But the animation boxes still keep changing the sizes although I have found the maximum and minimum limits of Xs, Ys and Zs. Do I need something more in my code?

This is the code I use for plotting:

```
% read the data
for k=1:length(FileNames)
   FName = plyfiles(k).name;
   plys=pcread(['Files\',FName]);
   pcshow(plys) % Capture the plot as an image 
   frame = getframe(h);
   im = frame2im(frame);
   [imind,cm] = rgb2ind(im,256); % Write to the GIF File
   if k == 1
      imwrite(imind,cm,filename,'gif', 'Loopcount',inf);
   else
      imwrite(imind,cm,filename,'gif','WriteMode','append');
   end
end
```

Comment: How do you display the images? Please include the shortest bit of code that replicates the issue! See [mcve].

Comment: `% read the data 
for k=1:length(FileNames)
   FName = plyfiles(k).name;
   plys=pcread(['Files\',FName]);
   pcshow(plys)
   
   % Capture the plot as an image 
      frame = getframe(h); 
      im = frame2im(frame); 
      [imind,cm] = rgb2ind(im,256); 

      % Write to the GIF File 
      if k == 1 
          imwrite(imind,cm,filename,'gif', 'Loopcount',inf); 
      else 
          imwrite(imind,cm,filename,'gif','WriteMode','append'); 
      end
end`

Comment: The code is from [https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/94495-how-can-i-create-animated-gif-images-in-matlab]

Comment: I’ve added this code to your question. You can >[edit]< your question at any time to correct or improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pcshow` will, just like `imshow` or `plot`, reset the axes it writes to. You can prevent this by setting

```
hold on
```

after creating the axes. However, now the point clouds will be shown on top of the previous ones, so you will also have to clear the axes before plotting a new one.

The easiest solution is, instead of `hold`ing the plot, to set the axes position every time after plotting. That is, do

```
set(gca, 'PropertyName', property_value)
```

after the `pcshow` call. The properties to set are, I believe, 'XLim', 'YLim', and 'ZLim'.

Comment: Thanks that works. In this case how to do normalization as the points seem very small

Comment: @PrashantMahato: do you mean that the plots do not fill the axes, or that the dots forming the plot are too small? In the former case, adjust the limits. In the latter case, you will probably find a 'MarkerSize' property for the dots that you can adjust. I don’t have the toolbox that contains the pointcloud functionality, so I can’t test that.